# Is there a way to turn an app into a website in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I built an application in React, is there a way that the same code will be used for a website?
I know Instagram is built on React and it also has a website, I wonder maybe you should add some link or something that it will open for me as a website?
Or maybe there is no such way and I have to build a website separately?

Comment: "I built an application in React" - Did you mean React Native? React and React Native are two different frameworks for two different platforms. In React you build websites/web applications, in React Native you build applications for mobile devices. It is true that you can use some logic (mostly API calls) and some components from each mentioned framework, but not everything. You will have to rewrite your React Native app in React to have a website.

Comment: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all, If you have written any code which is related to native functionality, then it can be challenging.
If you have only worked with views, images, and some of the basic functionality.
It can be done with `react-native-web` you can easily migrate your project to `react-native-web`.

If you project is created with `expo` they already provide `react-native-web` support.

Option 2: If you have some of the code you want to share and some is that you don't want to share or can't share.
You can use `renderProp` or `customHooks` pattern to reuse your logical code and seperate your view for `react-native` and `react js` apps.
If you want to reuse your views too, you can do those with `primitives`.
you can use `styled-component` primitives for that.

https://medium.com/react-native-training/sharing-code-between-react-web-and-react-native-applications-7f451af26378
You can get some idea here as well.